# Post File(pdf, doc, xls) using Documentum REST Services in iOS Objective C

Tags: objective-c, rest, xcode8, documentum, afnetworking-3

I'm working on an iOS App and I'm consuming Documentum REST services. Till now all "GET" Service part is working fine all data properly responded from server. But Now I need to do some "POST" part to upload Document files to server.

But I got stuck in Error from server.

So following code I'm using to upload Document files to server and also Provided Detailed Error Message.

Code:

```
(IBAction)btnPostDocumentToServer:(id)sender {
    NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demotpcode" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [self postMultipart:@"http://devser1:9090/dctm-rest/repositories/Mobile/folders/0b03445d800bfa1f" fileName:@"temCodeiOS" file:pdfData progress:nil params:nil];
}

(void)postMultipart: (NSString*) url fileName: (NSString*)name file:(NSData*) fileData progress:(UIProgressView*) progressView params:(NSDictionary*) parametersDictionary {
    NSDictionary *meta = @{@"properties":@{@"r_object_type": @"ecr_attachment", @"document_id": @"0903445d80210726",@"object_name": @"temCodeiOS.pdf",@"a_content_type":@"pdf",@"subject":@"new Doc from iOS Device"}}; //@{@"propreties": @{@"object_name": name}}; // You can modify this part to add more detail.    
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"] password:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[manager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:parametersDictionary constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:metaData name:@"metaData" fileName:@"metaData" mimeType:@"application/json"];
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:@"binary" fileName:name mimeType:@"text/plain"];
    } error:nil];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask; // Create resumable task
    uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted]; //Update the progress view
        });
    }
    completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
        }
    }];

    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

***Detail ERROR:***

> *Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000056350 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/vnd.emc.documentum+json" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://devser1:9090/dctm-rest/repositories/Mobile/folders/0b03445d800bfa1f } { status code: 400, headers {
>       Connection = close;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/vnd.emc.documentum+json;charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Thu, 15 Dec 2016 06:46:20 GMT";
>       Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
>   } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://devser1:9090/dctm-rest/repositories/Mobile/folders/0b03445d800bfa1f, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227374 61747573……>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}*

I'm using `Xcode 8.1`, `iOS 10.1 Simulator` and `AFNETWorking 3.0`. Please Help me to understand this and guide me as I'm using `AFNETWorking` First time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try formatting your question a bit more. Add effort when asking if you're expecting effort fro those who answer your question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong Content-Type value when calling Documentum REST service:

```
"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/vnd.emc.documentum+json"
```

I didn't use Documentum REST apart from Documetnum xCP 2.X, but in all cases `application/json` was the right Content-Type (I'm no saying it'll work, just check out what your service is expecting).

Comment: Thanks Miki For your Quick Response, Can you please tell me How and Where can I set correct Content Type?

Comment: I really don't know, I never wrote a line of Objective-C and from code you provided I don't see you are setting it anywhere.

Comment: Miki I also realise this by reading Error  I'm not setting any content type then How it sets to content-type: application/vnd.emc.documentum+json. In fact I need help to correct my headers value Thats why I had post question. Please share your thoughts it will be more helpful.

Comment: Did you paste all your code? Are there any framework boiler plate code that adds more code? Is maybe this Content-Type default type and you need to override it? Sorry, I can't help you anymore than this, hope someone else with more Objective-C experience will come across this.

Comment: Yes, specific to upload task I had paste all the code and in whole Project I had search that where I set Content-Type but its not set explicitly anywhere . I'm using AFNETWorking to accomplish this.